# How to select elements based on their position?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, web-frontend

**Short Description**:
 I want to select an element based on it's position on the viewport.

**Example use-case**:
for example consider the below image. When I navigate with keyboard, I want to move to `Block D` after `Block A` in mobile viewport. But which block is placed below `Block A` is not fixed. It can change based on the gap below `Block A`, or if additional blocks come in to picture (say `Block E`), then it might come below `Block A`.

**Question**:
Is there a way to select a block/element which is placed below Block A or any of the blocks for that matter.

**p.s.**
Again, I am aware of selecting via class names & navigating via DOM Order. But need help to navigate ***dynamically placed elements***.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your page is structured like this:

1. Gap between the top of the page and the top of Block A : 10px
2. Block A height: 100px
3. Gap between the bottom of Block A and the next Block (via margin-bottom for example): 10px

So the distance between the top of the document and the top of the unknown block after Block A is 120px. we call it "secondBlockDistanceFromTop".

Now you have to get a list of all possible blocks after Block A, you could do that by giving all of them a ".block" class and use "document.querySelectorAll". We store this array in  "blocks" variable.

Every DOM object's  distance from the top of the document can be calculated by this formula:

```
 let blockDistanceFromTop=el.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY
```

now you can use an array iteration method on the "blocks" array and check if each element's "blockDistanceFromTop" equals "secondBlockDistanceFromTop"

Comment: Interesting approach. Can you please help me by giving the example code for how to get a list of all possible blocks after Block A.

Comment: This really depends on the way the elements are rendered. Suppose each block is a div, inside a large container div that encompasses all blocks and has a class of ".container", then you can get a list of all blocks by running this line : "let blocksArr=document.querySelectorAll(".container>div"), or if each block has a ".block" class , you can get all of them in an array by running "document.querySelectorAll(".block"), in both situations, the index 0 of the array is blockA. If you want to omit it from the array, simply use "blocksArr.unshift()".

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @Erfan 's answer, here's what I implemented:

I'm fetching the position of each column from the left & all the elements at a distance (*say `x`*) are pushed in an array.

Now I'm making an object having key as left offset pixel distance (*`x`*) (as string) & value as the array of elements.

Something like this:

```
obj{
"245": [],
"478": [],
"789": []
}
```

Then all I'm doing is traversing the object. Which essentially reduces the problem to a 2D array traversal.

If I'm not very clear in my explanation, you'll get a better idea by looking at the [code here](https://github.com/pkrc267/50-Projects/tree/master/grid-offset) & the [live demo here](https://pkrc267.github.io/50-Projects/grid-offset/).